# Disabling edit on a JTextPane when click on a button (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Okay, so I am making a simple program that sets the ability to edit a JTextPane to true or false, according to which corresponding button is clicked.But, I can't figure out how to disable and re-able the edit-ability of the pane. JTextPane Here is the code I am struggling with:

```
`JTextPane Pad1 = new JTextPane();
        Pad1.setText("Edit Me...");
        Pad1.setBounds(10, 45, 188, 160);
        frmDuvalStudiosOffscreen.getContentPane().add(Pad1);


        JButton button = new JButton("Save");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //I want to make it when this button is clicked, it sets the ability to edit Pad1 to false.
            }
        });
        button.setBounds(10, 239, 89, 23);
        frmDuvalStudiosOffscreen.getContentPane().add(button);

        JButton button_1 = new JButton("Edit");
        button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //I want to make it when this button is clicked, it sets the ability to edit Pad1 to true.
            }
        });'
```

Please provide code and text. Thank You!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or ..

Comment: .. or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods for that:

- [`setEditable(boolean b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable(boolean)):

> Sets the specified boolean to indicate whether or not this TextComponent should be editable.

- [`setEnabled(boolean enabled)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled(boolean)):

> Sets whether or not this component is enabled. A component that is enabled may respond to user input, while a component that is not enabled cannot respond to user input

Comment: Could you provide an example with the code I provided in the question please?

Comment: Something like: `Pad1.setEditable(false);`. As aside note, use camel-case variable names (`pad1` instead of `Pad1`) in Java.

Comment: You see, I have already tried that way of doing it, but I get an error because it can not be resolved. Any other ways?

Comment: @DuvalStudios, *I have already tried that way of doing it, but I get an error because it can not be resolved.* - post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is create a JFrame with your JTextPane and a JCheckBox. When you click the checkbox you toggle the editable state of the text pane. There is no trick to doing this. We can't guess why get the "can not be resolved" error.

Comment: Sir, I managed to do it. And now it works. Thank you for the constructive criticism.